# What is wrong with my Merge Sort code?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, merge

I'm having trouble with Merge Sort in my computers class. I keep getting either errors or the original ArrayList returned.

I believe that Merge Sort involves splitting an array(list) in half recursively until there is only one element left, then, working from those individual elements, merging them in sorted order. This continues until the array(list) has been sorted. As for the actual sorting part, I am trying to insert into a new ArrayList the higher value between the two halves until they are both empty, in which case the filled ArrayList is now sorted.

Here's my current code:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> mergesort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {

    // Base case: if size of ArrayList is 1, return it.
    if (arr.size() < 2) {
        return arr;
    }

    // Else: Find the middle index.
    int middle = (arr.size() - 1) / 2;

    // Split into left and right halves.
    ArrayList<Integer> leftHalf = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
        leftHalf.add(arr.get(i));

    ArrayList<Integer> rightHalf = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = middle; j < arr.size(); j++)
        rightHalf.add(arr.get(j));

    // Recurse using the halves.
    mergesort(leftHalf);
    mergesort(rightHalf);

    // Sort and merge the two halves.
    return merge(leftHalf, rightHalf, arr);
}

// Merge two halves and sort them, and put the sorted values into the ArrayList sorted.
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> arr1, ArrayList<Integer> arr2, ArrayList<Integer> sorted) {

    // While the ArrayLists are not empty, add sorted elements to ArrayList sorted.
    while (arr1.size() > 0 && arr2.size() > 0) {

        // If the first element in A is greater than the first in B, remove A and add to ArrayList sorted.
        if (arr1.get(0) >= arr2.get(0)) {
            sorted.add(arr1.get(0));
            arr1.remove(0);
        }
        // Else, remove from B and add to ArrayList sorted.
        else {
            sorted.add(arr2.get(0));
            arr2.remove(0);
        }
    }

    // If there're still elements in A due to arr being odd
    // add them to C since they will be the largest.
    if (arr1.size() > 0)
        sorted.add(arr1.get(0));

    return sorted;
}
```

I would appreciate any help, but please don't give me a full implementation of the Merge Sort, since I want to actually learn how to do this for the future.

Comment: What is the simplest example which isn't sorted correctly and what do you see when you step through this code in your debugger?

Comment: BTW To improve performance try doing this without creating any new `ArrayList`s nor copying them nor using `remove(0)` which is expensive.

Comment: I always get the original array returned, even with simple things. I don't think I have a solid grasp of recursion yet, so it's really hard for me to identify what the problem is.

Comment: And how would I do this without creating new ArrayLists? I think I will have to improve the memory efficiency since I'm getting a java.lang.OutofMemoryError

Comment: Try creating a method `mergesort(List<Integer> list, int start, int end)` which doesn't remove anything from the List but can sort the values in place. This not the most CPU efficient but creates no extra memory, though you could create a method `mergesort(List<integer> list, int start, int end, List<Integer> scratchList)` where the scratch List is used as a re-usable list.  This will at most double your memory usage.  BTW If you can use `int[]` instead of `List<Integer>` this can be 1/5 of the memory usage.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. We have to use ArrayLists for the assignment, but I will try to use the indexes instead of creating new ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate problems I see.

First, you have infinite recursion.  Say you pass in a 4-value list and print your list size and middle values, you'll get:

`size 4, middle 1
 size 3, middle 1
 size 2, middle 0
 size 2, middle 0
 size 2, middle 0
 ... to infinity`

Remember that Java is aleardy doing integer division in your code.

Second, you're passing the `arr` parameter from `mergesort` to `merge`, nothing is ever getting removed from it.  So even if you made it past the infinite recursion you'd still end up with a larger list in the end, your original list plus anything you've `.add()`ed to it

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I fix the parameters in mergesort?

Comment: @JunlinYi Based on what you already have written, you want `sorted` in your `merge` function to be a fresh, local List that is then returned.  Your `mergesort` function would then set the `leftHalf` and `rightHalf` to the return values from their respective `mergesort` calls.  This approach means the `sorted` argument in `merge` is no longer needed.  This isn't the only way to fix what you have, but because of the way Java passes objects around it's probably the easiest to understand.  Even once you fix that you'll find your output isn't quite what you want, but that fix should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by MarquisDeMizzle, so that middle == 1 when arr.size() == 1.

```
    int middle = arr.size() / 2;
```

After main merge loop copy any remaining elements, and since you don't know if arr1 or arr2 go empty first, check both:

```
    // copy any remaining elements
    while (arr1.size() > 0)
        sorted.add(arr1.get(0));

    while (arr2.size() > 0)
        sorted.add(arr2.get(0));
```

If interested, you might want to learn bottom up merge sort. It skips all the recursion and just starts off assuming an array with n elements is n runs of size 1, just using indexing to do the merge back and forth between the original and a temporary array.